# Why is he using .every method in that line of code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I watch a tutorial where the author makes a e-commerce website.
Now he iterates through the products and returns only the products that match the filters

The filters structure is `{"color": "red", "size": "M"}` , or only one of the key/value pair.

```js
const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredProducts(
        products.filter((item) =>
            Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
                item[key].includes(value)
            )
        )
    );
}, [products, filters]);
```

This is what he wrote. I don't understand why he added .every method.

Comment: They are selecting all the products that match `every` filter (since there are multiple of them) ^^

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by saying "I don't understand why he added .every method.", but here's a explanation of the [`every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and the code.

> The every() method of Array instances tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

`Array.prototype.every` iterates & calls the callback function through array itself, and returns `true` only if every callback func returns `true`.

so, if you take a look at the code

```js
products.filter((item) =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
        item[key].includes(value)
    )
)
```

it iterates through all the products, and for each product it checks if the product satisfies all the filters by using `every` method and the `filters` object to filter the products that only match all current filters. By using `Object.entries` & `every` method, you don't have to change your code even if other filters are added to the `filters` object.

Comment: I thought that every method return a Boolean and therefore is not suitable for our purpose in the example. But from what you said I understand that every is used only to iterate through the array and not for the Boolean.

Comment: `every()` does return a boolean, and that boolean is being fed to the `filter()` function.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said, yes `every()` does return a boolean and it is used by [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, to judge if the current product should be excluded or not

Comment: If any one of the filters were not included in the item, it would return false. Not a great tutorial if that's not explained.